# iOS 8 app extension get image from safari

Tags: ios8, sharing

Im using app extension share on my app,

is working fine for giving me back the url and "message" for the sharing,
but my image appear as nil when logged

```
@interface ShareViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong)__block NSString *urlString;
@property (nonatomic, strong)__block UIImage *photo;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *msg;
@end

@implementation ShareViewController

- (BOOL)isContentValid {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Get msg
    NSExtensionContext *myExtensionContext = [self extensionContext];
    NSArray *inputItems = [myExtensionContext inputItems];
    for(NSExtensionItem* item in inputItems){
        self.msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [item.attributedContentText string]];
    }

    // get url
    NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;

    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
            self.urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url.absoluteString];
        }];
    }


    //img
    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
            self.photo = image;
        }];
    }

}

- (void)didSelectPost {
    // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

    NSLog(@"big fat fella");
    NSLog(@"msg: %@", self.msg);
    NSLog(@"url %@:", self.urlString);
    NSLog(@"im %@:", self.photo);

    // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
    [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[] completionHandler:nil];
}
```

so please note im getting url and message on didSelectPost, but image shows as null,

how to get image?
thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the image automatically generated on the share extension while sharing on Safari, use ***loadPreviewImageWithOptions:completionHandler:previewImageHandler.***

```
[itemProvider loadPreviewImageWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error){

   if(image){
        //do anything here with the image
   }

}
```

I'm able to retrieve the thumbnail auto-generated while sharing on Safari, but I'm unable to change the size of the image using:

```
NSString * const NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey;
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsitemprovider

Comment: image is always nil for images shared from Safari